# Dart webdev package activated globally, but webdev command is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, console, angular-dart, dart-web-toolkit

I was trying to create a project with angular dart, and I've activated webdev globally ad the documentation suggested by running "dart pub global activate webdev", but when I try to run "webdev server" it shows this error in console

```
Installed executable webdev.
Activated webdev 2.7.9.
macbook@Macbooks-MacBook-Pro ~ % webdev
**No active package webdev.**
macbook@Macbooks-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dart pub global activate` command installs the executable in *~/.pub-cache/bin*, so make sure that is in your PATH:

```bash
export PATH=$HOME/.pub-cache/bin:$PATH
```

Alternatively, run it using the Dart command: `dart pub global run webdev`.

I've found the version of *webdev* that works is dependent on other packages that your project might be using. Therefore, it is better to include *webdev* in your *pubspec.yaml* file (under *dev_dependencies* so the desired version gets installed when *dart pub get* runs) and run it using `dart run webdev`. If you run the globally installed version, it might become incompatible with your project.